Does Madness gain Mult if it’s your only Joker?
The description for the Madness Joker states:

When Small Blind or Big Blind is selected, gain X0.5 Mult and destroy a random Joker

Let’s say Madness is the only Joker you have. Will it gain Mult if you don’t have any other Jokers to destroy?

According to the Wiki:
Yes it will gain Mult, as: "The destruction of another Joker and gaining X0.5 Mult is independent, meaning that if no Joker is destroyed (either due to Eternal Stickers or having no other Jokers), this card will still gain X0.5 Mult."
And it can't destroy itself.
